# fatal error using custom library

Tags: c++, static-libraries, libraries

I made graphic library using directX 11.
But using my library, there is fatal error: cannot open d3dx11.lib.
My library include all directx header files and library directory.

I want user to use my library just include my library's header and lib file.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library has a dependency on another library.  Users of your library must install the other library as well, and configure their build system so that the compiler will find it.  Alternatively, it may be possible to bundle the other library with yours, but this can run into licensing problems (you may not have the right to redistribute the other library) or conflicts (if the user has the other library installed for other reasons).  If you redistribute, you'll need to consider where to put the needed components, and to be sure to include *all* of the needed components: header files and library files (both `.lib` and `.dll` under Windows, if the library is dynamically loaded).

Answer (score 0):

I had the error, too.
Usually it gets fixed as you install the DirectX SDK
just including the D3D files isn't enough.
As you also need the devel kit to be installed.
you can simply download it on microsoft.com .